# How to use CreateDialog in .wls file

Tags: dialog-window

I have following code, which can run in notebook.

```
CreateDialog[
 ExpressionCell[
  Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True], Selectable -> True, Deployed -> False]]
```

It will pop out a window.

I tried to run it in `.wls` file, but it said that

> FrontEndObject::notavail:
>      A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

So I add `UsingFrontEnd` , but still get nothing.

```
UsingFrontEnd[
CreateDialog[
 ExpressionCell[
  Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True], Selectable -> True, Deployed -> False]]
]
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `CreateDialog` just cannot work.
However, e.g. on Linux it is easy to let the image being popped up by the wls script, supposed that ImageMagick is installed and you can use the display function:
This is the script test.wls

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
Echo @ ("starting " <> $Version <> "  in " <> Directory[]);
(* generating the plot *)
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, SphericalRegion -> True];
(* exporting it to, e.g.  JPG, just works: *)
file = Export["sinPlot.jpg", plot];
(* this displays the file name *)
Echo @ file;

(* one possibility to open the file from within this script  *)
Run["/usr/bin/display " <> file];
```

On Windows, with ImageMagick installed as usual:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x+y^2],{x,-3,3},{y,-2,2},SphericalRegion->True];
file = Export["sinPlot.jpg",plot]
fName = FileNameJoin[{Directory[],file}]
RunProcess[{"cmd","/c","\"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick\\imdisplay.exe\"",fName}]
```

Comment: Actually, If I need static picture, I just need to use `<< JavaGraphics\`` . But I want to plot *Interaction* picture.

Comment: If you want to interact from the script: not possible. The only thing you could try to do is to start a full new separate Mathematica process, somehow from within your script.
Why don't you just use the notebook if you need a front end?